# Add data to Django form before it is saved?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In this simplified use case, I have a Django form that contains `MyField_1` and `MyField_2`.  The user fills out `MyField_1`.  Before the form is saved as a model, I want the computer to add `MyField_2` programmatically which is some data pulled in from another data source.  The view I currently have looks like this:

```
class MyCreate(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ['MyField_1']
```

How can I add the data to `MyField_2` before the model is saved?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are various ways to do it (for instance overriding the `ModelForm.save()` method) , however the one I recommend is overriding the `ModelFormMixin.form_valid()` method. So change your view like this:

```
class MyCreate(CreateView):
  model = MyModel
  fields = ['MyField_1']

  def form_valid(self, form):
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.MyField_2 = 43
    self.object.save()
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

Two suggestions:

- For all your CBV needs always take a look at the great CBV inspector tool: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/
- Plase use proper `lower_case_with_underscores` names for your fields. `MyField_1` should have been `my_field_1`.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks very good.  Thanks for all the other info too.  What does the `form.save(commit=False)` do?  Is it needed in this instance?

Comment: yeah, agreed, ccbv.co.uk is an awesome site for class based views. @Alexis

Comment: @serafeim why is the `form.save(commit=False)` do? What happens without it?

Comment: As @PiyushMaurya explained, the form.save(commit=False) will only return an instance of the Model without saving to the database. If you run form.save() without the commit=False the object will be saved to the database and if a required field is not filled through the form you'll get an exception. Without running form.save(...) you won't have a reference to the object that the form should create. That's why form_valid is passed the form variable so that you can get the object instamce from there.

Comment: perfect.  Makes sense now.  Thanks!

Comment: @Serafeim wouldn't the `return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)` cause the object to be saved a second time?

Comment: Yes it will. A better way to do it would modifying the form's instance, for example as described here: https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/#do-something-when-a-valid-form-is-submitted

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by(See second example for class based views):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.my_field_2 = #Put value here
        instance.save()
        return #Put return here
else:
    form = Form()
```

This way you can initialize any value to form which user don't input.

In Class based `CreateView` you can override `form_valid` method by:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.field_2 = # Put value here
    return super(YourCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Hello please notice that what you recommend is an answer for plain old functional django views, not classy ones.

Comment: @piyush what does the `save(commit=False)` do?  Is it needed?

Comment: @Serafeim I have just updated my answer for class based views too.

Comment: @Alexis `save(commit=False)` doesn't save value in database, means it doesn't commit those values to database at that time, so you can add some more values to data instance and then save into database later.

Comment: Hello @PiyushMaurya your answer is correct, that's another way to do it. I just copied over and modified the method I proposed from ModelMixin's form_valid.

Comment: I would avoid putting form logic in the view. instead, the logic should be in the form or the model itself. If you put logic in your view, you can't use it in any other view. your views should do as little logic as possible. In fact, I try to make it a goal to get to a point where I don't even have to override the get/post methods in my views.

Comment: as @Serafeim have commented, what one should override depends on the situation. Views are where we put our logic and I find no harm in putting logic in view, and its good practice to put logic in views. We use model and form in multiple views, so it's better to put login in views in situations like this question.

Comment: It really depends on your architecture and the size of your application. I think that the business logic could be in the views, in the models or maybe in special business rules modules. I would avoid putting business logic in form though, it simply doesn't feel right...

Comment: Awesome answer, God bless you with more knowledge

Answer (score 1):

I would override either ModelForm.save() or the models save(). You should push your logic as far back towards models as possible. If you're only going to create instances of this model without MyField_2, then you should override the models save(). This follows the encapsolation practice of object oriented programming which, when done correctly is quite a beautiful thing.

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    model = MyModel
    fields = ["field_1"]
    # no changes needed in form because the model itself will handle auto-population of field_2.

class MyModel(models.Model):
    field_1 = models.SomeFieldType(...)
    field_2 = models.SomeFieldType(...)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.id: # If true, this is being created. If false, this is just being edited and it already exists.
            # auto populate field_2
        else:
            # it's being edited and already exists so I'm guessing we just want this to do the default logic.
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you really want, you can even pass a variable through the models save methods **kwargs that tells the logic that it's being created by a form. In this case, you do the auto population but if it's not created by a form it could choose not to auto populate field_2

NOTE: I agree with @sarafeim that said you should use underscored names for fields and not camel case.

Comment: Hello @Ian Kirkpatrick - what you should override depends on your situation. I disagree with overriding the model's save method because then, whenever you save that model (from django admin, from a different view) you'll execute the view specific code. You don't always want to do that. Also the same is true for the form. A model form may be re-used with different views and you may want to have a different behavior for each view. Of course, sometimes it is importang to override the model save, for example when an action should always be performed when the instance is saved.

Comment: Yeah I kind of mentioned that in the beginning of my answer but didn't talk about why much. I agree, some times you may want different behaviors in which case, the logic shuld be moved a little bit higher up away from the models

Comment: Also, another reason for overriding the `form_valid` method of views that I forgot before is that you *usually* have access to the info you want to provide to your model through your view (for example you may want to set a value for request.user) and that info is not easy to be passed to your model's save. It is rather easy to pass it to your form (for example by passing the request object from the view to your form's `__init__` method) but it still requires some work -- one the other hand these parameters are there on the view just waiting to be used :)

Comment: Sorry the previous comment was a little too long. I have to say that I am writing all this because I've been bitten by all these things!  For example I was re-using a ModelForm in two different django views (but had forgotten about it). I changed one view to pass the request object to the form and changed the form accordingly to receive it. Guess what happened when I tried to call the other view :) Unfortunately this is a general problem with dynamic languages (in Java I would get a compiler exception if I changed a constructor) so I try to guard against such errors.